# QGLWidget in QScrollArea says "invalid drawable"

Tags: qt, opengl, pyqt, qglwidget

When I display my QGLWidget in the layout of my main QWidget, everything is fine.  When I put the QGLWidget into a QScrollArea, and then display, Python says:

```
2011-05-14 19:10:28.900 Python[68311:613] invalid drawable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the widget resizable seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: You should accept your own answer. (You don't get any rep, it just marks the question as answered.)

Comment: @TonyK, Thanks.  StackOverflow wants me to wait two days until I can accept.

Comment: This was happening to me just now.  In my case, the offending widget was a vtk widget inside a QSplitter that was sized very small.  As far as I can tell, the "invalid drawable" error was happening because the widget was being told to draw in such a tiny area.  When I added a line to resize the splitter first, it stopped complaining.  Your mileage may vary.