# QDockWidget - QGlWidget - invalid drawable when widget is dragged out from the dock

Tags: c++, qt, qglwidget, qdockwidget

I have a `QDockWidget` object in my application, which contains a `QWidget` object inside it. When my application runs, everything seems fine. However when I moved the widget from the `QDockWidget` (dragged it out from the Dock widget), I suddenly got these 10 lines of warning message on my console:

```
2011-10-23 21:06:22.296 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
2011-10-23 21:06:22.298 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
2011-10-23 21:06:22.299 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
2011-10-23 21:06:22.300 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
2011-10-23 21:06:22.300 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
2011-10-23 21:06:22.301 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
2011-10-23 21:06:22.302 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
2011-10-23 21:06:22.303 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
2011-10-23 21:06:22.304 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
2011-10-23 21:06:22.304 PerformanceVisualization[42898:903] invalid drawable
```

My main function is as follow:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(1);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    PerformanceModule *performanceModuleWidget = new PerformanceModule();// a QWidget object
    QMainWindow window;

    QDockWidget *performanceDockWidget = new QDockWidget(QObject::tr("Performance Visualization"), &window);
    performanceDockWidget->setWindowTitle("Performance Visualization Dock");
    performanceDockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
    performanceDockWidget->setWidget(performanceModuleWidget);

    //performanceDockWidget->show();

    window.addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, performanceDockWidget);
    //window.menuBar()->addAction(performanceDockWidget->toggleViewAction());
    //performanceDockWidget->hide(); // explicitly hidden
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

How can I solve this problem?.
 I saw a similar question here : [QGLWidget in QScrollArea says "invalid drawable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005368/qglwidget-in-qscrollarea-says-invalid-drawable), and based on that post, I tried to remove all the `setFixedSize()` function inside my widget and replace them with `setMinimumSize()` function, but that did not solve the problem. Any similar experience?. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Dockwidget property as given below and try

```
 performanceDockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::AllDockWidgetAreas)
```

If that doesn't work as well, change your Dockwidget property to resizable and then try.